# How does the LHC explore extra dimensions?

Tags: particle-physics, spacetime-dimensions, large-hadron-collider, particle-accelerators

The Large Hadron Collider (LHC) has been smashing particles for a long time and sometimes people say that it has found new dimensions. How is it even possible for a particle accelerator to find new dimensions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, no evidence for other dimensions has been found.

However, there are ways for particle colliders to detect other dimensions. One of the main ones is to see if any energy "disappears" under very certain circumstances...then it could've possibly gone into another dimension.

Another way is to look for particles that can only exist if there are other dimensions. These particles would be around 100 times the mass of the W and Z bosons (these carry the electroweak force). Particles of this size could really only be detected by the LHC.

Other ways include examining the evaporation of mini black holes and seeing what particles are produced and looking for gravitons - gravitons would quickly disappear into extra dimensions, leaving an apparent loss of energy, which could be detected.

I'll be updating this as I find more information, though these are some of the main ways. Hope this helps!

[This website](https://home.cern/about/physics/extra-dimensions-gravitons-and-tiny-black-holes) has more information.

Comment: so we can remove energy from our immediatly observable dimensions? that's pretty awesome!

Comment: @njzk2 Nonono. You are misunderstanding the word "dimension". I suspect because of comic book usage of the word. When we measure the energy of light for example, we notice that it drops off with the square of distance from the source. That is because the light energy spreads out in a sphere, and the surface area of the sphere grows with the square of the radius. If we notice that something is "dropping off" faster than "square of distance" then we can assume that that energy is spreading out more than into a sphere...

Comment: @Aron now you ruined it :( but it makes more sense that way.

Comment: It should be stressed that that the qualification "under certain circumstances"  to the "disappears"  is very important. The usual practice if momentum and energy disappear is to assign it to a neutral particle. That is how the neutrinos were discovered  to start with. Not new dimensions.

Comment: What are the possibilities of time travel with extra dimensions?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, that's a whole other ballgame altogether.

Comment: @heather then,what's that?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, see [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#Theory)

Comment: @heather so,it's really possible right?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, perhaps, but I think possible is much to strong  a word.

Comment: @heather What is more plausible method for time travel

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, none of it is really "most plausible" it's all kind of out there.

Comment: @heather some say that the 4th stuff in 4th dimension maybe time!

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, basically everyone agrees the fourth dimension is time, because of general relativity.

Comment: @heather then what would be the 8 stuffs in 11dimension (3 of them are length,breadth,height)

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, this sort of thing is honestly beyond our human brains; we cannot comprehend it. Though, we only have 7 dimensions to worry about (4 are length, breadth, height, and time). You might consider asking two new questions: one related to time travel and one related to dimensions, based on what you have been asking here.

Comment: What does it got to do with Higgs singlet?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @heather Leav it,Have you ever seen"The Flash" series?

Comment: @heather In that the particle accelerator ruptures the dimensional barrier and kind of energies like antimatter.dark matter is released from another one,is it possible?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, I think you should ask a new question; you obviously have a lot, which is a good thing, but comments aren't the best place to answer them. So, try asking a new question (you have several in the comments, maybe ask several new questions) and see what the answers are then?

Comment: @heather okay,last one what kinda math should i study for learning QM?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, I cannot say this enough: ask a new question, using the button on the top right of the page, next to "unanswered".

Comment: @heather LoL,okay but i dont wanna loose my reputation by asking stupid questions

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, if you ask them well, you'll be fine.

Comment: @heather but this is kinda comic book question

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP, then ask the non-comic book part or one of your many other questions. Just search for duplicates first.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand how experiments work. With very few very very basic exceptions, all experiments and their measurements involve a theoretical framework.

Fact is, we almost never measure things explicitly. For crude examples consider:

1. *Temperature:* a mercury thermometer measures length (that of the column of mercury). An electric thermometer measures either voltage, current, or resistance.
2. *Speed:* we usually measure position and time, and calculate the speed. The speedometer in your car very likely measures current.

With modern cutting-edge experiments, there is a lot more theory behind. The measures themselves are just numbers that the machines output (and again, the actual sensors are probably just measuring electric current, magnetic charge, etc., and for this they use the accepted electro-magnetism theories, say, which are very well established but they are theories, not facts). This data is processed by software designed following the principles of the accepted theory. Said like this, it doesn't sound very exciting, but it definitely has its merits.

In any case, experiments either confirm the numbers predicted by the theory, in which case they contribute to the theory's standing, or they contradict the theory, and then the theorists need to work on understanding what is wrong with the theory.

The bottom line is that experimental gadgets almost never measure directly the effects they intend to measure. They will measure some consequences of the effects, which are then studied according the accepted theories.

Comment: While this is good information about how experiments work, it doesn't really answer the OP's question about the detection of extra dimensions.